# Failing to build Air iPhone app (with a iOS native extension) with adt

Tags: objective-c, ios, flash, uiimagepickercontroller, adt

My issue is when I try to compile my .ipa using the adt tool (through Terminal) I get the following error:

```
ld: absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) used in -[MediaCaptureViewController         showCamera] from /var/folders/NP/NPNiEhuUEwGiPRg0Bym7Sk+++TI/-Tmp-/97f7f1f9-6d5e-4486-9ba0-    147ff50f7157/libcom.luxson.mediacapture.a(MediaCaptureViewController.o) not allowed in slidable image. Use '-read_only_relocs suppress' to enable text relocs
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

The iOS native extension pops up an instance of the UIImagePickerController and it works apart from the following line of code, which causes the above adt error:

```
cam.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie];
```

I have included the  MobileCoreServices framework in my project and added the following to my header file:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

**Other useful info...**

I'm using Xcode 4.2.

Project set to build with the following settings:

iOS Deployment Target: iOS 4.3
Enable Linking With Shared Libraties: No

Does anyone know why the adt is not liking my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to set Enable Linking With Shared Libraries = Yes, despite all the information that I read that said to set it to No!